# How to use matplotlib for debugging, without making it a dependency

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am developing a library of algorithms on graphs. During development, I regularly need to plot graphs generated during the algorithms, for debugging. I use matplotlib for this, so in my source code I need to `import matplotlib`.

But, I do not want matplotlib a dependency of the library, because the library itself does not need it.

How can I use matplotlib during development, but not make it a dependency of the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your plot commands inside a try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

try:
  plt.plot(...)
except NameError:
  # exception will occur if plt doesn't exist, which means you are in production.
  pass
```

Or if you don't want to use exceptions you can check if `plt` is defined in a conditional

```
if plt:
  plt.plot(...)
```

Instead of checking each library, you can also define a `debug` flag and check that flag to know if you are in debug or production mode

```
if debug:
  plt.plot(...)
```

When moving to production just comment the line that imports matplotlib, and set debug to False

```
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
debug = False
```